# Why do I get a jquery-ui error when loading Bokeh plot?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, bokeh

Loading the jquery-ui.min.js file but still getting jquery-ui is required to enable DataTable.reorderable error when trying to make changes to my Bokeh DataTable.

The error I receive: bokeh-tables-2.0.1.min.js:46 [bokeh] jquery-ui is required to enable DataTable.reorderable

My html JS and CSS loading code

```
<!--   JS Files   -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bokeh CSS and JS -->

<link
     href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.0.1.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
   href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.0.1.min.css"
   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.0.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- local js files -->
<script src="../static/assets/js/core/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../static/assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../static/assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>
<!-- Chartist JS -->
<script src="../static/assets/js/plugins/chartjs.min.js"></script>
<!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
<script src="../static/assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
<!-- Control Center for Material Dashboard: parallax effects, scripts for the example pages etc -->
<script src="../static/assets/js/black-dashboard.js?v=1.0.0" type="text/javascript"></script></body>
</html>
'''
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This help page clearly states not to *post images of code, data, error messages, etc.*. -- Please have a look if you expect help here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error would suggest that something is causing jQuery UI to not load or is conflicting with it. Do you see any other errors in Console? Can you test with just the essential libraries and see if you encounter the same error?